# Как в Vue отправлять обработчики событий в очередь?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Например, у меня есть две кнопки с @click, делающие одно и то же событие, пусть будет передвижение блока. Как добиться того, чтобы при нажатии на первую кнопку, а затем на вторую, если событие первой кнопки еще не завершилось, выполнять событие второй кнопки только после завершения события первой кнопки, в голове есть представление, что должна быть какая-то очередь, но нет понимания, как это реализовать. Пока что использую Vue через CDN.
Фрагмент верстки с обработчиками:

```
            <div class="lift-button" id="firstFloorBtn" @click="changeFloorUp(0)"></div>
            <div class="lift-button" id="secondFloorBtn" @click="changeFloorUp(100)"></div>
            <div class="lift-button" id="thirdFloorBtn" @click="changeFloorUp(200)"></div>
            <div class="lift-button" id="fourthFloorBtn" @click="changeFloorUp(300)"></div>
            <div class="lift-button" id="fifthFloorBtn" @click="changeFloorUp(400)"></div>
```

Метод:

```
methods: {
    changeFloorUp(toFloorPX) {

        let floor = this.bottom

        if (this.bottom < toFloorPX ) {


            let timerUp = setInterval(() => {

                this.up = true

                if(this.bottom !== toFloorPX) {
                    floor += 2
                } else if (this.bottom === toFloorPX) {
                    this.up = false
                    clearInterval(timerUp)
                }
                
                this.bottom = floor
            }, 20);

            
        } 
        else if (this.bottom > toFloorPX) {

            let timerDown = setInterval(() => {

                this.down = true

                if(this.bottom !== toFloorPX) {
                    floor -= 2
                } else if (this.bottom === toFloorPX) {
                    this.down = false
                    clearInterval(timerDown)
                }
                
                this.bottom = floor
            }, 20);
        }
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, вам нужна очередь. Для того, чтобы определить, что действие закончено, само действие нужно обернуть в промис, например, и резолвить по завершению. При срабатывании события клика нужно записывать метод в очередь. Далее, если очередь не пуста, вызывать функцию, которая лежит первой в массиве очереди. Далее проделать это всё снова, после того, как промис разрешится. пока в очереди не будет пусто.

Вначале приготовил [небольшой миксин](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-tdd-6gzfyw?file=/src/App.vue), но использовать его неудобно.

В итоге остановился на [более удобном варианте](https://codesandbox.io/s/createqueue-0d98gz?file=/src/App.vue).
Тут используется простая функция, которая создаёт обёртку для вашего метода. Обратите внимание, что теперь нужно ваш метод переместить в computed.
Для наглядности, в примерах выводятся логи начала выполнения функции и завершение. Нажимая на кнопку с номером 5, а через полсекунды на кнопку с 6, вы увидите как сначала выводится `start 5`, затем через секунду `end 5`, а потом только `start 6` и, опять таки, через секунду `end 6`.

**UPD**

```js
computed: {
  changeFloorUp(toFloorPX) {
    return createQueue((resolve) => {
      let floor = this.bottom;

      if (this.bottom < toFloorPX) {
        let timerUp = setInterval(() => {
          this.up = true;

          if (this.bottom !== toFloorPX) {
            floor += 2;
          } else if (this.bottom === toFloorPX) {
            this.up = false;
            clearInterval(timerUp);
            this.bottom = floor;
            return resolve();
          }

          this.bottom = floor;
        }, 20);
      } else if (this.bottom > toFloorPX) {
        let timerDown = setInterval(() => {
          this.down = true;

          if (this.bottom !== toFloorPX) {
            floor -= 2;
          } else if (this.bottom === toFloorPX) {
            this.down = false;
            clearInterval(timerDown);
            this.bottom = floor;
            return resolve();
          }

          this.bottom = floor;
        }, 20);
      }
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: Я так понимаю setTimeout(() => {...}, 1000) имитирует асинхронную функцию, но у меня не получается вместо него использовать мою функцию, которая длится неизвестное время.

Comment: Вы можете выполнять сколько угодно таймаутов и интервалов, но в *конце* вы должны в своей функции выполнить `resolve`. Это разрешит текущий промис и начнёт выполнение следующего. Вы можете выполнять `resolve` после того, как вы чистите интервалы. См **UPD**